# undefined method `project' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created project scaffold and stage scaffold with many to one association. Now I have added task scaffold with many to one association with stage scaffold. But I am not able to render task form correctly. 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQjv1.png)

routes.rb:

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :stages do
        resources :tasks
    end
  end
```

task form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: task, url: projects_stages_tasks_path(@stages, @stages.project), local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if task.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% task.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :task_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :task_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit 'Create', :class=>'button primary small' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

tasks_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [not able to render form in rails association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841158/not-able-to-render-form-in-rails-association)

Comment: @KamalPanhwar no, i got new error.

Comment: @Anuj I think you meant "yes,  but I've got new error". Please post this error as a new question.

Comment: @MarekLipka i have added error screenshot in this question as well.

Comment: BTW don't add errors as screenshots, paste them as text instead.

Comment: @MarekLipka Thanks for suggestion. but please see i have added code in this question.

Comment: Ad rem - I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. The direct reason of this error is quite obvious - you don't set `@stages` variable in your controller, yet you call `@stages.project` in your view. Now if you set `@stages` to be `ActiveRecord::Relation`, it would also throw an error because there would be no `project` method defined for this class. So this is a little bit of a mess and it's even not clear, what your intentions are.

Comment: @MarekLipka i generated a task scaffold that has many to one association with stage scaffold. now i wan to render task form and save data into task table of database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you wrote, I understand you're trying to create a `task` form as a nested resource. So I would do something like this: First of all, make sure you're setting `@project` and `@stage` variables in your `tasks_controller`:

```
before_action :set_project
before_action :set_stage

# ...

private

def set_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end

def set_stage
  @stage = @project.stages.find(params[:stage_id]) # Project#stages association is assumed to exist here
end
```

then, set your `@task` variable in the action itself, like this:

```
def new
  @task = @stage.tasks.build # Stage#tasks association is assumed to exist here
end
```

then, in your view, you can use regular form, where you wouldn't have to specify the url on your own (well, I guess):

```
<%= form_with model: [@project, @stage, @task] do |f| %>
```

etc.

Comment: it generated error -wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) in task form

Comment: <%= form_with [@project, @stage, @task] do |form| %>

Comment: Oh, right, `form_with` syntax is a little bit different. I updated my answer.